# Add each new dictionary result in the order of the columns of a dataframe

Tags: python

I am new to Python, but hope to explain the issue.

```
 dfrow - is a dictionary of a single regression summary
 results - is an empty dataframe with same columns as in dfrow
```

I would like to save regression results for each observation in the outer loop at the same time making sure column order in the inner loop. I am getting a result for the first observations but cannot move further, error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 109, in <module>
TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable
```

when I run this code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from statsmodels.stats import stattools as st
import statsmodels.api as sm
import collections
import datetime
import warnings
import scipy.stats

df_rent = import_rents()
df_return = import_ee_rets()
mostrecent = df_return.iloc[len(df_return) - 1]
mostrecentYYYY = mostrecent['Year']
mostrecentQ = mostrecent['Quarter']
mostrecentperiod = str(mostrecentYYYY) + "-Q" + str(mostrecentQ)
rentcols = df_rent.columns.values
colnames = []
#loop through the columns in df_rent until the column == the most recent period for which we have ee return data
for colname in rentcols:
    if colname != mostrecentperiod:
        colnames.append(colname)
    else:
        colnames.append(colname)
        break
rentcols = colnames
#subset df_rent to only include columns that also have ee return data
df_rent = df_rent[rentcols]
#change dtype of metro_code / metro columns to string for matching later
df_rent['metro_code'] = df_rent['metro_code'].apply(str)
df_return['Metro'] = df_return['Metro'].apply(str)

df = pd.read_csv('//x/Project/_data/raw_data/rent_change.csv')
metros = list(np.unique(df['metro_code']))
regress_result_names = [
                    'metro',
                    'num_lag',
                    'num_ma',
                    'num_AR',
                    'beta_x1_retmov',
                    'x1_se',
                    'x1_tstat',
                    'x1_pval',
                    'r-squared',
                    'reg_fstat',
                    'fstat_pvalue',
                    'durbin-watson',
                    'resid_var']
regress_result_names = pd.Series(regress_result_names)
results = pd.DataFrame(columns=regress_result_names)
row = 0
for metro in metros:
    for nlag in range(0, 5):
        for nma in range(1, 11):
            for AR in range(1, 5):
                y = df_rent[df_rent['metro_code'] == str(metro)]
                y = y.values.tolist()
                y = y[0]
                # delete first two columns of df_rent (they don't contain numeric data)
                y.pop(0)
                y.pop(0)
                #y = rent time series data for specific metro
                y = pd.Series(y)
                #x1 = lagged moving average data for given params
                df_return1 = df_return[df_return['Metro'] == str(metro)]
                df_return1 = df_return1.reset_index(drop = True)
                x1 = lagged_moving_avg(df = df_return1, metro_code = metro, nlag = nlag, nma = nma)
                #y and x1 dataframe
                y_label = 'y_Rent'
                x_lagMA_label = 'x1_LaggedMA'
                df1 = pd.DataFrame()
                df1[y_label] = y
                df1[x_lagMA_label] = x1
                if mostrecentQ == 1:
                    currmonth = "01"
                elif mostrecentQ == 2:
                    currmonth = "04"
                elif mostrecentQ == 3:
                    currmonth = "07"
                else:
                    currmonth = "10"
                #convert index to datetime to run the regressions
                currpd = pd.to_datetime((str(mostrecentYYYY) + currmonth), format='%Y%m')
                df1.index = pd.date_range(*(pd.to_datetime(['1990-01', currpd]) + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd()), freq='Q')
                #drop any rows that have missing observations
                df1 = df1.dropna()
                #df1.to_csv('//Nisfile01/x/Project - Real Estate Database/real_estate/odil/XandY.csv', index=True)
                reg = ARIMA(endog = df1[y_label], order = (AR, 0,0)).fit(trend = 'nc', disp = 0, tol=1e-20)
                resid_reg = reg.resid
                reg2 = sm.OLS(resid_reg, df1[x_lagMA_label]).fit()
                resid_reg2 = reg2.resid
                dfrow = {
                    'metro': metro,
                    'num_lag': nlag,
                    'num_ma': nma,
                    'num_AR': AR,
                    'beta_x1_retmov': reg2.params[0],
                    'x1_se': reg2.bse[0],
                    'x1_tstat': reg2.tvalues[0],
                    'x1_pval': reg2.pvalues[0],
                    'r-squared': reg2.rsquared,
                    'reg_fstat':reg2.fvalue,
                    'fstat_pvalue': reg2.f_pvalue,
                    'durbin-watson': st.durbin_watson(reg2.resid),
                    'resid_var': resid_reg2.var(),
                    }
                #create df for output called results
                for key in dfrow.keys():
                    results.loc[row, key] = list(dfrow[key])
                row = row + 1
```

Any help is very much appreciated.
P.S. Sorry for the messy code

Comment: Are you importing `numpy` somewhere?

Comment: Hi OldBunny2800, Yes

Comment: Can you please post your full code? Because there is nothing on `row = 0` that would raise a `TypeError`.

Comment: OldBunny2800, thanks for checking out!

Comment: So, it's raising an error on the `import` statement? Are you sure you have the right line number?

Comment: My fault, it is line 109 indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offending line is `results.loc[row, key] = list(dfrow[key])`.

You are trying to convert a single value, in this case a `numpy.int64` object, to a list. I assume that what you're trying to do, and correct me if I am wrong, is create a singleton list with the int64 inside it. If that's what you want to do, you should use:

```
results.loc[row, key] = [dfrow[key]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much OldBunny2800, I think I need some rest lol, am I eligible to give you a point, I am new here?

Comment: No problem! When your code is done, you may want to check out our sister site http://codereview.stackexchange.com. They can offer a much more thorough analysis of your code than we can here.

Comment: I appreciate it!